# Using custom tick lables on x-axis in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label

I have made a heatmap in D3js with day of year (integer between 1..365) on the x-axis, and time of the day (integer between 1..24) on the y-axis. For each hour in the year a dot is indicating the temperature by its color.

[image]

I have tried to find a way to map the names of the months to the right days of the year by using an ordinal scale but without luck. Instead I have created a new `xScale` variable with the month names. The problem is that the data not is showing up any more—now I only see the x- and the y-axis.

[image]

I guess it makes sense since the x-axis is based on dates, and the x-coordinates of each dot is based on integers (1..365).

So my questions are:

1. How do I convert the yearday (`d.day`) to a date, and will it work?
2. If I convert the `d.day` to a date, how would that affect calculations like this: `var days = d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.day; }) - d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.day; });`
3. Is there any better solutions to this problem?

Below is my entire code (sorry I did not know where to set the limit):

```
d3.csv("data-gitignore/temperatures_nyc.csv", function(error, dataset) {
    dataset.forEach(function(d) {
        d.tOutC = +d.tOutC;
        d.day = +d.day;
        d.hour = +d.hour;
    });

    //----------------------------------
    // VARIABLES
    //----------------------------------

    var days = d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.day; })
        - d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.day; });
    var hours = d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.hour; })
        - d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.hour; });

    var tMin = d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.tOutC; }),
        tMax = d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.tOutC; });

    var dotWidth = 1,
        dotHeight = 3,
        dotSpacing = 0.5;

    var margin = {top: 0, right: 25, bottom: 40, left: 25},
        width = (dotWidth * 2 + dotSpacing) * days,
        height = (dotHeight * 2 + dotSpacing) * hours;//200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    //----------------------------------
    // FUNCTIONS
    //----------------------------------

    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 11, 31)])
        .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([1, hours])
        .range([(dotHeight * 2 + dotSpacing) * hours, dotHeight * 2 + dotSpacing]);

    var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([tMin-5, (tMax-tMin)/2, tMax-5])
        .range(["#4575b4","#ffffdf", "#d73027"]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(d3.time.months)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));


    // Define Y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(2);

    // Zoom behavior
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([dotWidth, dotHeight])
        .x(xScale)
        .on("zoom", zoomHandler);

    function zoomHandler() {
        var t = zoom.translate(),
            tx = t[0],
            ty = t[1];

        tx = Math.min(tx, 0);
        tx = Math.max(tx,  width - (dotWidth * 2 + dotSpacing) * days * d3.event.scale);
        zoom.translate([tx, ty]);


        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.selectAll("ellipse")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.day); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.hour); })
            .attr("rx", function(d) { return (dotWidth * d3.event.scale); });
    }

    // SVG canvas
    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .call(zoom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Clip path
    svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


    //----------------------------------
    // DRAW ELEMENTS ON SVG CANVAS
    //----------------------------------


    // Heatmap dots
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .selectAll("ellipse")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("ellipse")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.day); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.hour); })
        .attr("rx", dotWidth)
        .attr("ry", dotHeight)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.tOutC); });

    //Create X axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + yScale(0) + ")")
        .call(xAxis)

    //Create Y axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});
```

Comment: Hey, did my answer work out?

Comment: Thanks alot @meetamit. It really helped me with you explanation. However, I still have a problem as commented on you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, establish the first day of the year as a reference date, `date0`. If the year is 2014, then it looks like this:

```
var date0 = Date.UTC(2014, 0);// Midnight on January 1st, 2014
```

`date0` is the number of milliseconds since 1970. To verify that, you can say

```
console.log(new Date(date0).toUTCString);

//> "Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
```

(Note the use of UTC here. It's best to stick with UTC dates everywhere, because it'll ensure that the user sees the correct date no matter what time zone they're in).

Given that, you can easily create a date object for any hour+day of the year like this:

```
// constants
var msPerHour = 3600000,
    msPerDay  = 24 * 3600000;

var after3days8hours = new Date(date0 + 3 * msPerDay + 8 * msPerHour);
console.log(after3days8hours.toUTCString())

//> "Sat, 04 Jan 2014 08:00:00 GMT"
```

So now you can compute a date per CSV row in your dataset:

```
dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    d.tOutC = +d.tOutC;
    d.day = +d.day;
    d.hour = +d.hour;
    d.date = new Date(date0 + d.day * msPerDay + d.hour * msPerDay)
});
```

That answers question #1.

Regarding question #2: Doing all that will enable you to calculate min/max as desired:

```
d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.date; })
```

and

```
d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.date; });
```

Even though `d.date` is a `Date` object, JavaScript should cast it back to a number of milliseconds for you. Also, all of the above would work even if you choose to skip instantiating all those `Date` objects. As in:

```
// without new Date
d.date = date0 + d.day * msPerDay + d.hour * msPerDay;
```

But `d3.time.scale` will need to be passed dates as opposed to numbers, so for example `xScale(d.date)` would need to be `xScale(new Date(d.date))` if `d.date` is a number. If you ever see console errors coming out of d3, suspect that you might have forgotten about this and passed in a number instead of a Date.

For the `cx` calculation, for any given hour, you'll need to find the midnight of that day. You can either use your `d.day` like this:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
  return xScale(new Date(date0 + d.day * msPerDay));
})
```

Or, you can work out of from `d.date` like this:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
  var msAtMidnight = Math.floor(d.date / msPerDay) * msPerDay
  return xScale(new Date(msAtMidnight));
})
```

To use `d.date` for `cy`, you can say:

```
var msSinceMidnight = d.date % msPerDay
```

Finally, because you'll be working with UTC dates, you need a UTC time scale instead of the regular one you have there. D3 has that scale for you:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale.utc()
```

and I think the `yScale` domain should be `[0, 23]`.

Regarding question #3: This is probably the best solution for this, specifically because having an x-axis whose ticks are months (Jan, Feb, etc) is probably most appropriate. And to get those ticks, you kinda have to use a time scale, because the number of days per month is variable, and accounting for that without a "time-aware" scale is a lot of work.

Comment: I still have some problems. Instead of creating a date from the original data, I have just added a date column in the data set—at this point I am more or less free to define how the input data should look. From the console I can see that the dates looks like this `Thu Dec 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` after it has loaded. However, my scale function (`var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 11, 31)]).range([0, width]);`) is not working. It returns `NaN`.

Comment: @Christoffer that's odd. Seems like it should work just fine. Do you get expected results if you `console.log(xScale.domain())` and `console.log(xScale.range())`?

Comment: it was my fault. It is working like a charm, I just gave the wrong input to the `xScale` function. I really like Stackoverflow when one can get answers like yours. Thanks again.